# How to Remove Welcome Message bar in MAGENTO

Tags: magento, php

I have gone through all tutorials online and unable solve the problem.
I am using magento in my [Website](http://www.ondeal247.com/), and I can't remove the welcome message bar. From configuration if I set welcome message box empty the welcome bar still shows, their must be some coding to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Navigate to file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/header.phtml and comment next lines:

```
<div class="header-language-background">
    <div class="header-language-container">
        <div class="store-language-container">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
        </div>

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('currency_switcher') ?>

        <p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?> <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('accountLinks') ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

After that remove cache. Hope, this should help.

Comment: sorry, it didnt work, moreover it added one more message bar http://prntscr.com/82z2lh

Comment: If you remove (or comment) the html code provide by Valery Statichny, the welcome message bar disappear.

Answer (score -4):

Add this at the end of  your template css:

```
.header .welcome-msg {
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: Edit /skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/styles.css and at line 3203 change float:left to display:none. Then clean cache and try again

Comment: on line 3204 i found float: right; and replace it with display:none and still didnt work :(

Comment: In my opinion css display:none hack it's not a best pratices, except if you want display the welcome bar in some cases later.

Comment: The good css hack will be something like : `.header-language-background{display:none;}`